# Trying to normalize text data by removing caps and quotation marks having issues

Tags: python, string

Trying to remove all instances of quotation marks and capital letters in my local outputtext.txt file

This code is based on this website
https://www.thepythoncode.com/article/text-generation-keras-python

```
sequence_length = 100
BATCH_SIZE = 128
EPOCHS = 30
text = open("outputtext.txt",'r',encoding="utf-8")
text = text.lower()
text = text.translate(str.maketrans("", "", punctuation))
```

However when I run the code; the lower function and the translate function both return errors

lower:AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'lower'

translate: AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'translate'. Did you mean: 'truncate'?

I've tried screwing around with the read and write permissions but that doesn't seem to work?

Comment: Is your goal to: "remove all instances of quotation marks and capital letters in my local outputtext.txt"?

Comment: That is my goal yes

Comment: See my answer below. Because I don't know the contents of your file, I added a hypothetical example. Do you need to write the edited contents back to the file?

Comment: one quick question. in my outputtext.txt file I have a few hundred lines. How would I select them all. I realize you would put something in the lines[]

Comment: The readlines() function reads in the entire file. So, whether your file has one or a few hundred lines, the code should work as intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File contents:

```
Sam" goes "To" the StOre.
```

Read in file, edit file, print file contents

```
with open('outputtext.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    lines = lines[0].lower().replace('"','')
    
    # output: sam goes to the store.
    print(lines)
```

Read in file, edit file, write lines to new file

```
with open('outputtext.txt', 'r') as infile:
    lines = infile.readlines()
    lines = lines[0].lower().replace('"','')
    with open('new_outputtext.txt', 'w') as outfile:
        lines = outfile.write(lines)
```